# Execute task in another thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new in Rails developing, and I have one question. There the following code:

```
def create
    @order = current_user.orders.create!(order_params)
    OrderMailer.send_order_info(@order).deliver 
end
```

This code creates a new order, render json result and send e-mail about it. Mail sending takes some time, and I think I should do it in another thread or something similar. Please, give me advice how I can do it good. Thanks!

Comment: You can use [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use delay the email sending. You could do it using Sidekiq, Delayed Job or Resque for example.

You will also be able to delay any other jobs with these gems.

You should look at the docs and see which one is the best for your use.

I personally use Sidekiq but [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) is the easiest to install if you only want to use it for mailer.

Comment: I.e. JSON response will be rendered immediately, and e-mail task a little bit later?

Comment: Yes, the mail will be sent from another thread and that will not freeze your application. All the mail will be queued in delayed queue and be sent out from delayed job thread.

Comment: Which gem can you suggest as the easiest gem?

Comment: Delayed Job, in the readme you will see how to delay your mailer ;) https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Answer (score 0):

We use Spawn for this: it's changed its name to "Spawnling" now

https://github.com/tra/spawnling

Very easy to use: (in the controller)

```
@user = User.create(params[:user])
spawn do
  @user.do_some_slow_background_stuff
end
```

or, if you want to monitor whether the background process has finished yet (@spawn_id is the pid)

```
@user = User.create(params[:user])
spawner = spawn do
  @user.do_some_slow_background_stuff
end
@spawn_id = spawner.handle
```